# maven dependency version known at runtime bound to property

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project (maven 3.0.5) having an open range dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>[1.0.0,2.0.0)</version>
 </dependency>
```

At runtime the dependency is resolved with the latest one I need from the 1.X branch.
Now, suppose it is the 1.3.

I need to update as well a deploymend descriptor with the runtime resolved artifact version: following similar questions I tried with the antrun plugin doing something like:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
         <configuration>
           <tasks>                              
        <replace file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/jboss-deployment-structure.xml"
                 token="@@@" value="${project.dependencies[0].version}"/>
                  </tasks>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

to change the "@@@" placeholder inside:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
       <dependencies>
        <module name="com.ericsson.oss.mediation.cliengine.api" slot="@@@" />           
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But the variable:

```
${project.dependencies[0].version}
```

is never bound.
There is a way to achieve that?

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using wildcard dependencies, as this would make your build non-repeatable. I'm not sure if property resolution works for antrun plugin, but i think there is no need to use this, either: Mavens builtin resource plugin should be good enough for that.

Comment: I know it's pretty unreliable use the wildcard dependencies, but the dependencies I rely upon change automatically triggered by jenkins job (when changes are found) not by human hand. 
So it may happen that an artifact I rely upon change frequently.